# Catch text before it's pasted into textview

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a textview and when something is pasted into it from the clipboard I need to intercept that text and do some preprocessing on it before it ends up in the textview.

I've tried listening to the "PasteClipboard" event which doesn't give me a way to modify the incoming text. and the "textview.Buffer.Changed" event which fires after the pasted text makes it into the textview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you use Buffer.Changed, do you actually see the pre-modification text flash up before your modified version appears?

Comment: unfortunately no, by the time buffer.changed gets triggered the text I'm trying to catch has already been placed into the textbuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK your best option is to postprocess the text after it's been inserted - the InsertText event on the TextBuffer has arguments that tell you the position and size of the inserted text, so you can remove, process and re-insert it. You would of course want to avoid catching 1-char insertions (keystrokes) and your own re-insertions, but that's trivial.

The only other option I can think of is to re-implement paste support, by catching the paste key command, middle-click, etc. - but note that the command keys can be overridden in users' gtkrc files, so implementing this correctly could get hairy.

It might also be worth asking in the #gtk+ IRC channel on irc.gnome.org.

Comment: Is there anything similar to WndProc in GTK? I haven't worked with Mono for a few years and I admit, I am a little rusty with the framework.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. It's event-based ("signals" in C) all the way down. The Windows/X/Carbon message systems are hidden by the GDK platform abstraction.

Comment: Of course, even if there were, you'd also need an equivalent of "WM_PASTE", which TBH is more the issue here.

Comment: That said... in general in situations like this, the built-in behaviour is handled by a signal handler added by the widget itself. So to pre-empt built-in behaviours, you can put [GLib.ConnectBefore] on your signal handler to make it get connected *before* the built-in handler, then optionally set arg.RetVal to true if you want to prevent the signal propagating to the widget's handler. However, this only works if the EventArgs is a sublass of SignalArgs, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some short googling, I found the following documentation on [Gtk.TextBuffer](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3AGtk.TextView.PasteClipboard)  and  [GTK alternative to .net WndProc in Mono](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=858085). It appears that you might want to add the **[GLib.ConnectBefore]** attribute to your code to access GTK's WndProc method. Beaner's code above would probably work with slight modification for the GTK framework.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent of WndProc in GTK.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a help to you, but I am catching the WM_PASTE message in a custom control that implements TextBox. I get the GetText from the clipboard into a string variable and if it matches what I am looking for I make my changes to the variable and set the .Text to my variable and swallow the event so the textbox neer gets it. If it is not what I am looking for, but is allowed I just pass the event on with base.WndProc(ref m).

Sample:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
    {
        string clipboardVin = Clipboard.GetText();
        string newVin = "";
        if (SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            newVin = Text.Replace(SelectedText, "");
        }
        else
        {
            newVin = Text;
        }
        newVin = newVin.Insert(SelectionStart, clipboardVin);
        if (!vinRegEx.IsMatch(newVin))
        {
            m.Result = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(true));
            MessageBox.Show("The resulting text is not a valid VIN.", "Can Not Paste", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help me. I'm trying to do this on linux under gtk.

Comment: Should the c# tag be removed from this question?

Comment: No, it's C#. GTK# is a .NET/Mono wrapper for the cross-platform GTK+ toolkit, like System.Windows.Forms is a wrapper for Win32 GUI.